# Error: Cannot find module '../core-js/object/define-property' showed when I open a next render page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want practice an ssr app with next.js, and after install the react, react-dom, and next, then start the serve, access the page in localhost:3000, but find this error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '../core-js/object/define-property'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.../core-js/object/define-property (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:114:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:23:31)
    at Object../node_modules/_@babel_runtime-corejs2@7.1.2@@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/createClass.js (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:186:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:23:31)
    at Object../node_modules/_next@8.0.3@next/dist/pages/_error.js (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:449:44)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:23:31)
    at Object.1 (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:588:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:23:31)
    at /Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:91:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yuchenyang/Cs/fe/.next/server/static/development/pages/_error.js:94:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question the file which invokes this error?

Comment: just add some sample code in the ./pages/index.js
```function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello nextjs</p>
    </div>
  ) 
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: fix it with use npm or yarn not cnpm